# Call service error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exchangeToMono (spring-webflux version 5.3.12)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I am using Spring Boot MVC and using WebClient (spring-webflux version 5.3.12) call other API.
*spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.4*
*spring-webflux:5.3.12*
*JDK: openjdk:14.0.2*

> Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'reactor.core.publisher.Mono org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$RequestHeadersSpec.exchangeToMono(java.util.function.Function)'

details

```
[
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doDispatch",
        "fileName": "DispatcherServlet.java",
        "lineNumber": 1055,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doService",
        "fileName": "DispatcherServlet.java",
        "lineNumber": 943,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "processRequest",
        "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
        "lineNumber": 1006,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doGet",
        "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
        "lineNumber": 898,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "service",
        "fileName": "HttpServlet.java",
        "lineNumber": 634,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "service",
        "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
        "lineNumber": 883,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "service",
        "fileName": "HttpServlet.java",
        "lineNumber": 741,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
        "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
        "lineNumber": 231,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
        "lineNumber": 166,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "WsFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 53,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
        "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
        "lineNumber": 193,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
        "lineNumber": 166,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
        "fileName": "RequestFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 30,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "vn.com.mbbank.cmv.lib.core.config.http.RequestFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 119,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
        "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
        "lineNumber": 193,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
        "lineNumber": 166,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 320,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "invoke",
        "fileName": "FilterSecurityInterceptor.java",
        "lineNumber": 126,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterSecurityInterceptor.java",
        "lineNumber": 90,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "ExceptionTranslationFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 118,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "SessionManagementFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 137,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
        "fileName": "OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 140,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 119,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 111,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 158,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "RequestCacheAwareFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 63,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
        "fileName": "BasicAuthenticationFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 155,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 119,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
        "fileName": "DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 52,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 119,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 216,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 200,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 200,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 176,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
        "fileName": "OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 160,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 119,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
        "fileName": "OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 160,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 119,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "LogoutFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 116,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
        "fileName": "CorsFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 92,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 119,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilter",
        "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
        "lineNumber": 334,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doHeadersAfter",
        "fileName": "HeaderWriterFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 92,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter"
    },
    {
        "classLoaderName": null,
        "moduleName": null,
        "moduleVersion": null,
        "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
        "fileName": "HeaderWriterFilter.java",
        "lineNumber": 77,
        "nativeMethod": false,
        "className": "org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter"
    }...
```

Comment: Errors like this generally come from trying to outsmart the Spring Boot starters. So I suspect you have tried to upgrade versions or outsmart it. But without seeing your Maven POM or gradle build file that is impossible to answer.